# Java deserialization of List of Objects

Tags: java, list, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to desirialize byte[] to list of object but getting

```
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 724F3041 error.
```

What I am doing wrong?

```
 public static List<Object> getDeserialized(byte serializeStringAsArray[]) throws IOException, Exception {

    ByteArrayInputStream  bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializeStringAsArray);
    ObjectInputStream  in = new ObjectInputStream(bais);

    List<Object>  objectAsDeserialize = (List<Object>) in.readObject();

    bais.close();
    in.close();
    return objectAsDeserialize ;
}
```

Many Thanks

Comment: I don't think the problem is in those lines of code.

Comment: This means that the byte array you're trying to deserialise is corrupt. You might want to look at the code that serialises the List (assuming you have it)

Comment: The name `serializeStringAsArray` of the parameter drops a hint that the array does not contains serialized list of object. Are you sure the array consists of what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stream header is the giveaway: 724F3041. This data was not produced by an `ObjectOutputStream`, so you can't read it with an `ObjectInputStream`.

Comment: Thank. Digging the code I have noticed the data was encoded after the serialized.